# Limit access to GCP

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

Our company recently start using GCP. Mainly, we use bigquery to store data.
We provide access to GCP based on user account(gmail).
Now, we want more secure access to all GCP services because the staff can connect to bigquery everywhere as long as they have account created by our company. We want to limit access to GCP services if they are not in head offices or branch offices physically.
We want to secure data stored in Big Query not with user account information but in a more secure way.

Below are the solutions that I came up with.

- allow access to company's project in GCP only thru company's VPN(= allow certain ip addresses(vpn ip addresses) only using VPC Service Controls?)
- allow company's ip addresses only which are dynamic ip addresses(but can expectable)

Since I am very new to GCP. I am not sure these suggestions realistically work. Or, wonder what other most cost-effective options to acheive this.
If possible, I also want to know if there is way to download credential file per user and access to GCP only if using user account and downloaded credential file(This credential file will be downloded in company's devices only)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704832/12428794) answer your question?

Comment: @Serhii Rohoza it helped me a lot. Thank you so much! i will try to study more about it.

Comment: *@user770239* Thank you! I posted that solution as a community wiki answer here, please upvote/accept it if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an answer provided by *@Felipe Hoffa* at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704832/12428794) to make it more visible. Feel free to change or enhance it.

You can have BigQuery behind the VPC:

- https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls
- https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview

[image]

> Access from the internet to managed resources within a service perimeter is denied by default. Optionally, you can enable access based on the context of the request. To do so, you can create access levels that control access based on a number of attributes, such as the source IP address. Requests made from the internet are denied if they do not meet the criteria defined in the access level.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting onboard into GCP I would recommend to check on this article about [Google Cloud Service Account](https://cloudberry.engineering/article/google-cloud-service-accounts-security-best-practices/).
Aswell here you have the predefined roles and permissions for [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).
Lastly to avoid any suprises I would recomend to deep into controlling [BigQuery cost](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/controlling-costs)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the feature I was looking for. I might not know how to use it, but i will study the links you provided me. I really appreciate it. I will be back with  more questions again since I might struggle with settings of these cloud service accounts.